# Linker command failed. CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH not working

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clang, clang++

Trying to build a simple application with EASTL lib and having an error while building  `cmake --build .`
I don't know where is my mistake.
Getting error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc++.so.1, needed by /home/user_name/.conan/data/eastl/package/lib/libEASTL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc++abi.so.1, needed by /home/user_name/.conan/data/eastl/package/lib/libEASTL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/usr/bin/ld: /home/user_name/.conan/data/eastl/package/lib/libEASTL.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::lock()'

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/md5.dir/build.make:97: bin/md5] Error 1

gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/md5.dir/all] Error 2

gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

My **CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(MD5Encrypter)

add_definitions("-std=c++17")

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH_USE_ORIGIN ON)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH ON)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH OFF)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH ON)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../.lib")

conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(md5 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(md5 ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Have `libEASTL.so` in `{project_dir}/.lib`

Comment: My guess would be that your code isn't linked to the same standard library as the libraries you're using

Comment: @AlanBirtles How to link the same standard library?

Comment: You probably need to alter your Conan profile

Comment: @AlanBirtles hmm..., I see my Conan profile and can't understand what I do to alter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution.
The problem was is missing package `libc++-dev`
So, the solution is to install it:
`sudo apt install libc++-dev`